# Pygame "fnaf" moving method

Tags: python

im new to pygame but im trying to make a game for a friend of mine
He loves so much five nights at freddy's that he has a yt channel about it

In the code i already made a room to move, a local to open the cameras other to open the doors and one to hide from the enemies
In my plans im trying to just make the game only in this room, the "control office" and just see the other places from the cams. But i struggling with the moving method out of the screen

At the moment i was trying to make a map from lists
As example:

```
#1 for walls, 2 and 3 for enemies and 5 for the office
map=[
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
[1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]
```

And change the place of the enemy, test the side positions and move him randomly to the possible locations every determinated time. And for the position it is, the camera shows a file of the image of the place with the enmy there

But im not finding how to move him in the list, how to set the time and how to make the interaction of the map outside of the screen with the office on screen

I would like to see if there is other methods for this

Comment: This is a very broad question and the site is for very specific technical problems, you can get help here if you narrow it down. Hope you have lots of fun programming your game!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyyy, just made this code to solve my problem with de moving out of screen method

```
import time
import random

def move(mapa,enemy,last):
    for x in range(len(mapa)):
       if enemy in mapa[x]:
            l_old=x #linha que tava
            break
    for x in range(len(mapa[l_old])):
        if enemy==mapa[l_old][x]:
            p_old=x #pos que tava
            break
    able=[]
    if mapa[l_old-1][p_old]==0:
        able.append("up")
    if mapa[l_old+1][p_old]==0:
        able.append("down")
    if mapa[l_old][p_old-1]==0: #and last!="left":
        able.append("left")
    if mapa[l_old][p_old+1]==0:
        able.append("right")

    move=random.choice(able)
    last=move
    if move=="up":
        mapa[l_old-1][p_old]=enemy
        mapa[l_old][p_old]=0
    if move=="down":
        mapa[l_old+1][p_old]=enemy
        mapa[l_old][p_old]=0
    if move=="left":
        mapa[l_old][p_old-1]=enemy
        mapa[l_old][p_old]=0
    if move=="right":
        mapa[l_old][p_old+1]=enemy
        mapa[l_old][p_old]=0

    return mapa,last

mapa=[
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]
enemy=2
last="left"

while True:
    mapa,last=move(mapa,enemy,last)
    print(mapa)
    time.sleep(4)
```

It iterates in the lists positions, sinalizes if it's able to move adding the relative position to a list, then sort one of the possibilities, move the enemy number and make the old position as 0

After ending the ond of the def there's just some sample on how it will works